# MSVC: why calling a static function generates more assembly code than calling an instance method?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-optimization, return-value-optimization

When disassembling my application, I have noticed that MSVC generates more assembly opcodes when I'm calling a static method compared to an instance method. This is true even when both functions are identical (so the instance method is not using `this`).

Code example:

```cpp
struct matrix4
{
    float m[16];
    static const matrix4 identity;

    static matrix4 translation1(float x);
    matrix4 translation2(float x) const;
};

func(matrix4::translation1(0));
func(matrix4::identity.translation2(0));
```

The generated code will look like this:

```
        call    static matrix4 matrix4::translation1(float)       ; matrix4::translation1
        push    16                                  ; 00000010H
        mov     esi, eax
        lea     edi, DWORD PTR $T2[ebp]
        pop     ecx
        lea     eax, DWORD PTR $T2[ebp]
        rep movsd
        push    eax
        call    void func(matrix4 const &)                ; func

[...]

        mov     ecx, OFFSET static matrix4 const matrix4::identity      ; matrix4::identity
        call    matrix4 matrix4::translation2(float)const       ; matrix4::translation2
        push    eax
        call    void func(matrix4 const &)                ; func
```

For my application, I care about the generated file size. It looks like I should replace all my static methods with instance methods, which seems really surprising to me. I'd rather avoid that because it means changing a lot of code. Did I miss anything?

Repro: https://godbolt.org/z/o3x5vKGdK (compare block1 and block2)

I have noticed similar issues with other compiler flags (with and without /Os). The same happens whether the method is inlined or not.

Clang doesn't seem to have this behavior. If that's a MSVC optimization bug, is there a simple workaround?

(I noticed the problem when I upgraded my code from Visual Studio 2010 to more recent VS versions. VS2010 was generating a smaller executable.)

Comment: The code you have shown doesn't compile (there is no `static` member of `matrix4` named `identity`), and the generated assembly doesn't match the code shown, either (`translation1()` and `translation2()` don't take `float` parameters).  The code you have shown doesn't match your demo code on Godbolt.

Comment: Sorry, I simplified the code slightly. It's updated now, but that shouldn't make a difference (see the godbolt link for reference).

Comment: You might consider turning off the [Buffer Security Check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gs-buffer-security-check?view=msvc-170) using the `/GS-` flag, that will omit some of the extra assembly code. But you will still see `func(matrix4::identity.translation2(0));` generate less assembly than `func(matrix4::translation1(0));`, so there is obviously some other optimizations going on behind the scenes.

Comment: You're making legacy 32-bit code, so the calling convention differs for member functions, `thiscall` (`this` arg in ECX) vs. `stdcall` it looks like.  Also, the non-static function just calls `translation2()` with a pointer to `static matrix4::identity`, no copying a return value between stack locations.  If you want efficient code, usually MSVC is not the best choice.

Comment: I'm not sure *exactly* what is making the difference here (seems to be copying the matrix into a new variable?), but what if you make the static function `__fastcall`?

Comment: When you tested this did you compile each one separately or were they in the same function?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Even when the calls are inlined, I still see a difference in output (https://godbolt.org/z/3cT7vKjbr). When trying different calling conventions, I didn't get any luck, but I'll try again.
The function calls are scattered in my codebase, there can be multiple in the same function.

I'll try to switch compiler later, but the migration will take some time.

Comment: I've tried many variations, there's always a clear difference on the call site. For example, with /O2 and x64 you can see a copy of the matrix data: https://godbolt.org/z/TsnYfWc43